# SQL Server sending mail with hyperlink

Tags: html, sql-server, sql-server-2008, email, sql-server-2012

I have a HTML File with below code :

```
<html>
<head>
<style type="text/css">
 .row { vertical-align: top; height:auto !important; }
 .list {display:none; }
 .show {display: none; }
 .hide:target + .show {display: inline; }
 .hide:target {display: none; }
 .hide:target ~ .list {display:inline; }
 @media print { .hide, .show { display: none; } }
 </style>
</head>
<body>
 <div class="row">
   <a href="#hide1" class="hide" id="hide1">Expand</a>
   <a href="#show1" class="show" id="show1">Collapse</a>
   <div class="list">
   <ul>
     <li>Item 1</li>
     <li>Item 2</li>
     <li>Item 3</li>
    </ul>
   </div>
 </div>
</body>
</html>
```

When I Open this file with Explorer, Firefox or chrome; expander hyperlink work correctly. but when I send this code with database mail of SQL Server, expander hyperlink not work correctly.

I use below code for send mail from database.

```
execute msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail 
        @Profile_name = 'Support',
        @recipients = @Recipients,
        @subject = 'Database Report',
        @body_format = 'HTML',
        @body = @Htmlbody
```

I want to send mail report from sql server each day and want to use expander on it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue is unlikely to be related to SQL Server. There are a lot of restrictions in email html markup. And it strongly depends on the email client (gmail, outlook etc.). For example you cannot use classes only inline styles. So you cannot just take the html page that worls fine in browser and send it as email. I suggest you to read some email html markup tutorials.